# Is there a Magento-like ecommerce platform in Java?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Does anyone know of an e-commerce platform similar to Magento (in terms of level of capability and sophistication), but written in Java?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+e-commerce - Take your pick ;) Broadleaf seems to become quite popular lately.

Comment: Currently 2 best competing ecommerce platform written in java are ATG, IBM websphere ecommerce. Both are paid software, does have well defined api & supports lean customization.

Comment: FWIW Magento is uses a fairly Java-esque approach in its construction